# Save JSON file to internal memory

Tags: android, json

Hey Guys I am learning JSON right now. So at first I want to learn how to create one. So I wrote this code ...

```
public void writeJsonFile() {
    username = usernameField.getText().toString();
    password = passwordField.getText().toString();
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try{
        jsonObject.put("username", username);
        jsonObject.put("password", password);
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I have a Problem...How I can save the jSON file into the internal memory in the appfolder? And what is the code to call and read that file again?

Comment: Check this link, It describe how to save file in the answer <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681158/write-json-to-a-file>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving the JSON per se is not really a good option. What you could do is:

1. Transform the JSON file into a String and save the String using [SharedPrefferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) and when you get it from the SharedPrefferences transform it back into a JSON.
2. Use a database (Realm), map your JSON to a model and save that model in the database.
3. I wouldn't do either of those for Username/Password cases. But I would use SharedPrefferences and store both valued independently with different keys.

Don't forget to [encrypt sensitive data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909999/encrypt-data-in-sharedpreferences) in the SharedPrefferences.

If you really really want to save the info in a file, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40168829/2540578).

Comment: Okay, is it a bad way to save username and password in a txt. in the memory?

Comment: Well, it's not saved in the memory. It's saved on the internal storage. And no, it's not a good idea to save it as plain text. You should encrypt the information. Edited main answer with link.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `jsonObject.toString` and then [save and read like in the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376807/how-to-read-write-string-from-a-file-in-android). After reading a string from disk you would need to call

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourString);
```

to parse it back into a `JsonObject`.

There are also tools like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) that help you do object to json serialization that can help avoid some of this work.

Comment: But when I use the code to read the file I'll get back something like this: "[B@9cd886"

Comment: Hmm that looks like an object instead of String contents